# Bash wait the completion of an iteration inside loop

Tags: bash, matlab, for-loop, synchronization, wait

I wrote a bash script in which there is a for loop, inside this for loop I invoke a matlab script that is heavy for my laptop. Is there a way to wait the completion of an iteration an then start the other?
here there is the part of my script:

```
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing file... $f"
  cp $f $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/
  echo "generating data for matlab ..."
  ./../../../matlab/graphic_file_gen $f > data_matlab.txt
  if [[ $f == *fsr12* ]]; then
    fullPath=$BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/data_matlab.txt
    cd /home/myname/Desktop/test/
    fsr=12;
    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -r "fullPath='$fullPath'; fsr='$fsr' ; fit_exp_real_data" > $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/result_matlab.txt</dev/null&
    cd -
  fi  
  cd $BASEDIR/$DECADIMENTI
done
```

at the end the question is : is there a way to wait the completion of this line?

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -r "fullPath='$fullPath'; fsr='$fsr' ; fit_exp_real_data" > $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/result_matlab.txt</dev/null&
```

before starting the next iteration?

Comment: Just take off the `&` on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply remove the trailing `&` to make the command to be executed on the foreground.

By default shell commands execute on the foreground, and the shell wait for them to complete to continue to the following line. But if you add an `&` at the end of a command, it executes on the background, and the shell continues its execution immediately after the start of the command, without waiting for it to finish.

Answer (score 1):

If you had other processing you wanted to do between starting the `matlab` script and continuing on to the next iteration, you could insert a `wait` statement to pause until `matlab` completed:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab ... &
# Do more here
wait
cd -
```

However, here you don't seem to need to run the script in the background at all, so just omit the `&`:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab...
# Script pauses while matlab runs. Once it returns, the script continues
cd -
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Ben Voigt's and Álvaro Gutiérrez's insights I noticed a part of the script that appears to be superfluous. Try this modified version:

```
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing file... $f"
  cp $f $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/
  echo "generating data for matlab ..."
  ./../../../matlab/graphic_file_gen $f > data_matlab.txt
  if [[ $f == *fsr12* ]]; then
    fullPath=$BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/data_matlab.txt
    cd /home/myname/Desktop/test/
    fsr=12;
    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -r "fullPath='$fullPath'; fsr='$fsr' ; fit_exp_real_data" > $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/result_matlab.txt
    cd -
  fi  
  cd $BASEDIR/$DECADIMENTI
done
```